# NiFi - InvokeHTTP not making GET calls while taking parameter from incoming FlowFile

Tags: get, apache-nifi

I have an `InvokeHTTP` processor that makes a GET that accepts an `author` variable from an incoming `FlowFile` as input. However, `InvokeHTTP` does not appear to be doing anything with the input: https://www.pastepic.xyz/image/LKc34

I tested the Remote URL in a browser with an author from one of the input flowfiles, and it returns JSON as expected.

Remote URL: `https://www.reddit.com/user/${author:urlEncode()}/comments/.json?limit=100`

Data Provenance shows only DROP and ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED events. Shouldn't there be FETCH, CLONE, and/or FORK events?

The `author` from the incoming `FlowFile` is in those DROP and ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED events. The input processor is an `EvaluateJsonPath` whose only output is the `author` field, and the property name is `author`.

Also, I tested hardcoding a username in the Remote URL and disconnecting the input `FlowFile`. That worked and made the request as expected, returning output. So appears there's something wrong with the interaction between the input `FlowFile` and `InvokeHTTP`.

I should be getting back JSON from `InvokeHTTP`. But it appears that the requests are not being made in the first place, failing silently so to speak. `Read/Write` and `Out` are empty, and I'm not getting errors.

Comment: Are flow files just continuing to build up in the queue before InvokeHttp? or does it look like they are being removed?

Comment: Also, what is the Run Schedule of InvokeHttp on the Scheduling tab of it's configuration?

Comment: Run Schedule: 1 sec

Comment: They are building up in the queue (right now, 3,213), but also decrementing simultaneous with the `In` for InvokeHTTP increasing. It looks like `In` and `Tasks/Time` are slowly accumulating flow files, so while the queue is currently at 3k, the `In` is at ~300. Also `In` and `Tasks/Time` always have the same number and update together.

Comment: Do you have any of the relationships of InvokeHttp auto-terminated? is it possible flow files are being processed and sent to one of the auto-terminated relationships and you can't see them?

Comment: InvokeHttp feeds two other processors with "Response" relationships, if that's what you mean: https://www.pastepic.xyz/image/LKOnf

Comment: Ok according to the docs it will only send a flow file to "Response" if it receives a 200 response code, unless "Always Output Response" is set to true, which it defaults to false, so you may want to try changing that to true and see what happens

Comment: Also may want to route the other relationships somewhere to see whats happening, maybe connect "sucess", "retry", "no_retry", and "failure" to their own LogAttribute processors, right now they must be auto-terminated since the screenshot doesn't show them connected anywhere

Comment: Ah thanks! Yes it appears the `author` property which is the output of `EvaluateJsonPath` is not making it into the `invokehttp.request.url`: `https://www.reddit.com/user//comments/.json?limit=100`, and so the response is 404 not found. How do I get the `author` property into the request url?

Comment: If you want to show example json and your config for EvaluateJsonPath we can try and see why it is not getting the right value, or alternatively you can check the value a couple of ways, you could insert LogAttribute processor right before InvokeHttp and see what attributes get logged, or you could stop InvokeHttp and right-click on the queue and list queue, then look at an individual flow file and see what the attributes section has for author

Comment: The issue was `EvaluateJsonPath` had Destination set to `flowfile-content` instead of `flowfile-attribute`. That fixed it. Thanks for your help!